# ASIO library - handlers not called

Tags: c++, unix, boost, boost-asio

i have a problems with ASIO boost library. The problem are asynchronous functions.

This is simple server code.

```
void handle_accept( const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
    std::cout << "Someone connected" << std::endl;
}

void handle_read( const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
    printf( "Message: %s \n", somedata);
}

int main()
{

std::cout << "Starting server ....\n" << std::endl;

try
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::socket  mysocket(io_service);
    tcp::acceptor myacceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 5000));

    myacceptor.async_accept( mysocket, boost::bind( &handle_accept, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    mysocket.async_receive(  boost::asio::buffer(somedata, 1024)  , boost::bind( &handle_read, boost::asio::placeholders::error) );
    io_service.run();

    std::cout << "END. \n" << std::endl;
    sleep(5);

}  catch (std::exception& e)
{
  std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
return 0;
```

}

and client code here

```
int main()
{
std::cout << "Starting client ....\n" << std::endl;

try
{
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "localhost", "5000");
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::socket mysocket(io_service);

boost::asio::connect(mysocket, endpoint_iterator);

sleep(5);
sprintf( somedata, "This is a message i sent.");
mysocket.send( boost::asio::buffer(somedata, 1024)  );

}  catch (std::exception& e)
{
  std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

So, How it should work. Server should wait on connection from client, when client is connected, it should call handle_accept. When client is connected, handle_accept is really called, but it also calls handle_read even no data is recieved !!! why ? client sends data after 5 seconds after making connection.

thank you very much.

Comment: You normally start the receive/send cycle from inside the `handle_accept` function. Check the Asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Comment: You need to also check the error code in the handlers, since the fact that the handler has been invoked does not imply that it has succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receive completes immediately because it cannot wait because it has nothing to wait for. No data will ever be received on a TCP listening socket. Call `async_receive` on your connected sockets only.

Comment: so, it means, i should call async_receive when handle_accept is called as client is connected ?

Comment: Yes. And generally you call it again before your receive handler returns.